# ssl, co issue (issuer) instead of Self Signed?

Tags: linux, ssl, certificate

Instead of self signing each website i make which is accessible online but is not meant for the public i would like to create an issuer which i'll import into my trusted issuer and sign multiple sites. This say if someone else signs my domain (lets say the server has been compromised) i'll be alerted since it doesnt match our issuer.

How do i do this? i only seen ways to self sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenSSL comes with a script called "CA.sh" that will automate pretty much everything you're looking to do.  Google "CA.sh openssl" and run with it.

Comment: +1. I liked this http://octaldream.com/~scottm/talks/ssl/opensslca.html however 1) can i make it so i dont have to type a password everytime i restart apache 2) the p12 file is for the site. Do you know the cmd to export the actual CA so anything i sign with it is valid?

Comment: I figured the 2nd out. I'd like to know how i can restart apache without writing the password for my ssl files

Comment: nevermind i asked a question and got an answer. My SSL is complete. http://serverfault.com/questions/160768/stop-apache-from-asking-for-ssl-password-each-restart