# Restart webserver without entering a password?

Tags: apache-2.2, security, ssl, nginx, https

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [stop apache from asking for SSL password each restart](https://serverfault.com/questions/160768/stop-apache-from-asking-for-ssl-password-each-restart)

When I created my SSL certificate I used a pass phrase in the key. Whenever I restart my web server (Apache or Nginx) they ask for a password:

Apache:

> Some of your private key files are encrypted for security reasons.
>   In order to read them you have to provide the pass phrases.
>
> Server www.example:443 (RSA)
>
> Enter pass phrase:

Nginx:

> Starting nginx: Enter PEM pass phrase:

Entering the password each time is fast getting annoying and I'm worried about downtime when the machine is next rebooted.

Is there a way to automatically provide the PEM pass phrase when the webserver is restarted? or do I have to get the SSL certificate re-issued using a key where the pass phrase has been removed?

If I remove the pass phrase, what are the security implications? Is it anything to worry about?

Answer (score 7):

[See Warner's Answer to almost the exact same question a day or two ago.](https://serverfault.com/questions/160768/stop-apache-from-asking-for-ssl-password-each-restart/160773#160773)

Answer (score 3):

Answering each question in turn:

> *1) Is there a way to automatically provide the PEM pass phrase when the webserver is restarted?*

Apache has the [SSLPassPhraseDialog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslpassphrasedialog) to automatically answer the SSL pass phrase question.

> *2) do I have to get the SSL certificate re-issued using a key where the pass phrase has been removed?*

The pass prase can be removed from the key without needing to get the certificate re-issued. The key is your secret and you can do anything you want with it including making it unsecure:

```
> cp server.key server.key.org
> openssl rsa -in server.key.org -out server.key
[enter the passphrase]
```

> *3) If I remove the pass phrase, what are the security implications? Is it anything to worry about?*

Yes, if the private key is no longer encrypted, it is critical that this file only be readable by the root user. If your system is ever compromised and a third party obtains your unencrypted private key, the corresponding certificate will need to be revoked immediately or the attack could put up a website pretending to be yours.