# Nginx wont restart after adding ssl

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, vps

I added some modifications to my `root@mypage:/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

when I do `sudo service nginx restart`  the server gives back this error: `Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

If I run `nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf` the out put is

`Enter PEM pass phrase:
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful`

Can someone advise my about what I'm doing wrong? I'm totally blank here

here is the `root@mypage:/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file

```
 server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    server_name mypage.com;
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env    production;
    root         /home/deploy/mypage/current/public;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
 }

 server {
    listen 443;
    server_name mypage.com;
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env    production;
    root         /home/deploy/mypage/current/public;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }

    ssl                   on;
    ssl_certificate       /etc/ssl/certs/secure.mypage.com.1.2019.chain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key   /etc/ssl/private/mypage.com.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;


    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers     on;
    ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;

 }
```

I used this guide https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D2P5cRMi0fQ and this guide http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#optimization for reference during the setup.

Comment: Could you add some logs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restart webserver without entering a password?](https://serverfault.com/questions/161768/restart-webserver-without-entering-a-password)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your private key is encrypted so you have to type password before nginx start or decrypt the key

```
mv /etc/ssl/private/mypage.com.key /etc/ssl/private/mypage.com.org.key
openssl rsa -in /etc/ssl/private/mypage.com.org.key -out /etc/ssl/private/mypage.com.key
chmod 400 /etc/ssl/private/*.key
```