# nginx won't start after I have updated the ssl certificates?

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, csr

So, I have recently changed the hosting of my website to Amazon EC2 and am using the key and certificates which I purchased from Godaddy. So this certificate was already being used for my another website domain which is hosted in Godaddy itself. As I was allowed to add other domains to this existing certificate - I did so and then downloaded the .zip of the certificates.

I copied the private key from the Godaddy Hosting (cpanel), after adding these new domains.

Now, I copied the bundle certificate and the key to my EC2 instance and pointed the path fom nginx to the .crt and privatekey file.

I see that the ssl works fine in chrome but it doesn't in Safari.

> As per my research - its my Server i.e. EC2 instance, where the private key is created
> and I shouldn't use the private key from the Godaddy Cpanel and expect it to be trusted.

So, to fix this I created a Private key file and a CSR file on my server to rekey the certificates and then redid the process above this time using this new privatekey in nginx but the same doesn't seem to work and throws the following error:

```
Dec 14 16:13:00 ip-172-31-42-11 systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Dec 14 16:13:00 ip-172-31-42-11 nginx[820704]: Enter PEM pass phrase:
Dec 14 16:13:00 ip-172-31-42-11 nginx[820704]: Enter PEM pass phrase:
Dec 14 16:13:00 ip-172-31-42-11 nginx[820704]: nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate key "/var/www/sslnew/openssl/PRIVATEKEY.key": PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey() failed (SSL: >
Dec 14 16:13:00 ip-172-31-42-11 nginx[820704]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Dec 14 16:13:00 ip-172-31-42-11 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 14 16:13:00 ip-172-31-42-11 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 14 16:13:00 ip-172-31-42-11 systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
```

This is how my nginx configuration for ssl looks like :

```
server { 
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php;
        server_name xxx.in www.xxx.in;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

    listen 443 ssl; 
    ssl_certificate /var/www/sslnew/openssl/gd_bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/www/sslnew/openssl/newkey.key;
   }
```

---Edit---

So, now I have removed the passphrase from the privatekey file using

```
openssl rsa -in key.pem -out newkey.pem
```

and now I am getting the following error :

```
Dec 14 16:56:16 ip-172-31-42-11 systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Dec 14 16:56:16 ip-172-31-42-11 nginx[820971]: nginx: [emerg] SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey("/var/www/sslnew/openssl/newkey.key") failed (SSL: error:05800074:x509 certificate routines::key values mismatch)
Dec 14 16:56:16 ip-172-31-42-11 nginx[820971]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Dec 14 16:56:16 ip-172-31-42-11 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 14 16:56:16 ip-172-31-42-11 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 14 16:56:16 ip-172-31-42-11 systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

Does it mean I need to redo the CSR process also with Godaddy now or just removing the passphrase from the private key was enough ?

Comment: welcome, what research has been already done to solve this problem?

Comment: @djdomi I just updated my question with the same.

Comment: Did you set a passphrase on your private key?

Comment: yes, I did add a passphrase there

Comment: That passphrase is needed for startup. Remove it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [stop apache from asking for SSL password each restart](https://serverfault.com/questions/160768/stop-apache-from-asking-for-ssl-password-each-restart)

Comment: thanks @vidarlo , I just updated my question - removed the passphrase from the privatekey file but now it says there is a mismatch ?

Answer (score 1):

So, it was enough to get rid of the passphrase.

And for the next issue, as per my last edit in the question, Finally I found the answer here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49311134/1503130

So Godaddy issued an intermediate certificate which I had to chain and create a combined certificate and then it all worked.